# Adding framework causing 'Undefined symbols for architecture arm64' issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, cocoapods

I have a weird problem in iOS coding with CocoaPods.

I just got a project that can run on my current device and I want to add OpenCV support to run a face detection algorithm on it.

So I tried to use the way I am familiar with. Adding CocoaPods and OpenCV support.

**The screenshot of Podfile**

[image: Screen Shot]

At this stage, everything is the same, so the project can still run.

Then as normal, I add `$(inherited)` to **Other Linker Flags** and **Library Search Path**. I hit run again, it is giving me **errors**!!!

**The screenshot of Errors**

[image: ScreenShot]

The 'Undefined symbols for architecture arm64' doesn't mean anything to me. The functions it point to already exist in the original project. It is **not** brought into the project by adding the OpenCV framework, so if the original project can run, these functions should be defined!

**I am sure all the changes  are just these two things!**

So I have two questions here:

1. Why is the CocoaPods and the `$(inherited)` flag causing this issue?
2. How to fix it? (Run OpenCV)

Environment info:
MacBook Pro (Mid 2015) on macOS High Sierra 10.13
iPhone 6s on iOS 11.0.3
Xcode 9.0.1
pod --version 1.3.1

Comment: I usually fix this error by changing the 'Build Active Architecture Only' flag to true in build settings.

Comment: [Don't post images of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3750257)